# How do I mount my Samsung Galaxy Ace phone (USB connected)?

Tags: 12.04

I attached a Samsung Galaxy Ace mobile phone using a data cable. Here is the output of `dmesg`:

```
[ 1644.813452] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access SAMSUNG GT-S5830 Card 0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 1644.815236] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 1644.820822] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1683.927497] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, large block/inode numbers, no debug enabled
[ 1683.930666] SGI XFS Quota Management subsystem
[ 1683.941496] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
[ 1726.272098] CE: hpet increased min_delta_ns to 20113 nsec
```

I did some surfing and download the NTFS driver. I used `pmount` command as `pmount /dev/sdb` .But didn't get any result. Previously I was using Ubuntu maverick and in that no such issue was there. Why does this brake after upgrading the OS?

Answer (score 1):

I tried several things.The best answer i found out is mount command. The command is:- **mount -t ntfs(type) /dev/sdb(device) /media/mydevice(dir)** 
Please note that the type , device and dir can be changed according to the device.
In Last i will recommend to use 12.04.2 LTS or version higher that this ex:-**13.04(Raring)**.In these latest version there is no need to manually mount the device.It will mount automatically :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but it seems ubuntu is not coming with autofs pre-installed.

It will stay in the background and auto-mount any external device you attach to your system. In my opinion it is a must to be installed.

You can do so by searching in the Ubuntu software center or using the below command:

> sudo apt-get install autofs

Comment: After installing autofs it seems to work, we just need to run service autofs start in order to get the device mounted. Nevertheless, the device's files/folders permissions can not be determined thus we can't read/write anything beyond the root folder on both the internal or external memory. Do you know of any other tricks that we should run in order to have full bi-directional permissions to the files/folders? Thanks in advance.